# expess session doesnt work , just a simple code

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

why my req.session.userid always undefine on path '/get' after i added a value on session.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const session = require('express-session')

app.use(session({
    secret:'sdasdas',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized:false
}));
app.get('/user',(req,res)=>{
    req.session.userid = 'test123'
})
app.get('/result',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.session.userid)
})
app.listen(8080,(err)=>{
    console.log('sucess')
    if(err){
        console.log('failed')
    }
```

Comment: Path /get doesn't exist in your code snippet. Please fix the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing `response send`. Since u never send the session to `user/client`. It will never send back in next `session`.

```
app.get("/user", (req, res) => {
  req.session.userid = "test123";
  res.send({"tes":"test"})
});
```